# Multiple DLLMain functions

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I have a C++ program that has a `DLLMain` function that runs some code when this program (which is actually a DLL) is loaded by another one. This is working fine.

Now, when I compile this same C++ program this time including an `.obj` file (made from C code) that already has a `DLLMain` function defined, the compiler (in this case, VS2010 for Windows) complains that the `DLLMain` is already defined.

Without using the linker flag `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` how can one have both `DLLMain` functions (defined in the C and the C++ programs) coexisting and running in the same final DLL?

FYI, in GCC for Linux using `static void __attribute__((constructor)) _my_initializer(void)` works fine (i.e. both initializers can coexist in the same final `.so` file and run).

Answer (score 1):

Rename one of the `DLLMain` functions to something else (I'll call it `CDLLMain`), then call that renamed function from the other `DLLMain`.  Care must be taken when deciding where to make the call to `CDLLMain` (first thing in `DLLMain`, last before returning (if safe to do so), or somewhere in the middle), in handling the return value from it (can you continue in `DLLMain` or do you need to return), and potential duplicated effort in the two `DLLMain` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the C source create a second DLL project and have your C++-based DLL depend on that second library. Each DLL can have a DllMain of its own. You could even use forwarding exports so that it appears that your C++ DLL exports the symbols from the secondary library.

A forwarding export is done with the following in your library's .DEF file:

```
EXPORTS
EntryName=realldll.RealEntryName
```